# adding values to fixed text in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have hundreds and sometimes thousands of rows in my excel document. I have a column with some text, where i want to implement two column values into that text.

I want the result to be in column "Q". 
"This is an example how " + (column "P"value) + " I want the text to be" + (column "R").

The text is always the same, but the values differ. I want to do this for each row.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **P1** and **R1**, in **Q1** enter the formula:

```
="This is an example " & P1 & " I want the text to be " & R1
```

[image]

You can manually copy this formula downward or program your macro to do the copying.

**EDIT#1:**

To apply formatting **within** the formula-string, use something like:

```
="This is an example " & TEXT(P1,"0.00%") & " I want the text to be " & R1
```

Thus any set of numeric values that you are splicing together with text can be separately formatted!

Comment: @lass9509  See my **EDIT#1**